# React JS: Refactoring Redux Selectors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, selector

I am using several selectors to get the boundaries on which to set my Google Maps. They basically return the lowest and highest lat/lng points from the data. The code works but I feel this is really messy and can be re-factored, but i'm not too sure how.

Here is the code:

```
const getMinLat = data =>
  data.reduce((prev, current) => {
    return prev.coords[0] < current.coords[0] ? prev : current
  })

const getMaxLat = data =>
  data.reduce((prev, current) => {
    return prev.coords[0] > current.coords[0] ? prev : current
  })

const getMinLng = data =>
  data.reduce((prev, current) => {
    return prev.coords[1] < current.coords[1] ? prev : current
  })

const getMaxLng = data =>
  data.reduce((prev, current) => {
    return prev.coords[1] > current.coords[1] ? prev : current
  })

const getBounds = data => [
  {
    lat: getMinLat(data).coords[0],
    lng: getMinLng(data).coords[1],
  },
  {
    lat: getMaxLat(data).coords[0],
    lng: getMaxLng(data).coords[1],
  },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just traverse list once:

```
const getBounds = data => 
    data.reduce(
        ([
             {lat: minLat, lng: minLng}, 
             {lat: maxLat, lng: maxLng}
         ], 
         {coords: [lat, lng]}
        ) =>
       [
            {
                lat: Math.min(minLat, lat), 
                lng: Math.min(minLng, lng)
            }, 
            {
                lat: Math.max(maxLat, lat), 
                lng: Math.max(maxLng, lng)
            }
      ], 
      [{lat: Infinity, lng: Infinity}, {lat: -Infinity, lng: -Infinity}]
    )
```

I agree in advance that readability is not the advantage here. But it goes through list just once.

Also after getting used to destructuring syntax it's quite clear that `Math.max` and `maxLng/maxLat` goes together to decrease possibility of using wrong variable

[UPD] and there is no need to use `Infinity/-Infinity` as start values(I used them to highlight idea behind). for longitude/latitude we may use `180/-180` as most extreme values

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this

```
const getMin = (data, index) =>
  data.reduce((prev, current) => (prev.coords[index] < current.coords[index] ? prev : current))
    .coords[index];

const getMax = (data, index) =>
  data.reduce((prev, current) => (prev.coords[index] > current.coords[index] ? prev : current))
    .coords[index];

const getBounds = data => [
  {
    lat: getMin(data, 0),
    lng: getMin(data, 1)
  },
  {
    lat: getMax(data, 0),
    lng: getMax(data, 1)
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it more concise by using `Array.map()`:

```
const getCoordsArray = (data, index) =>
  data.map(o => o.coords[index]);

const getMin = (data, index) =>
  Math.min(...getCoordsArray(data, index));

const getMax = (data, index) =>
  Math.max(...getCoordsArray(data, index));

const getBounds = data => [getMin, getMax]
  .map(m => ({
    lat: m(data, 0),
    lng: m(data, 1),
  }));
```